# How to get a section of a matrix in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I have this matrix in openCV:

```
  cv::Matx44d m;
```

and I want to get the top left 3x3 matrix out of this matrix. What is the simplest and fastest way to do this?

I can do it in the following ways:

```
cv::Matx44d m;
cv::Matx33d o;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
       o(i,j)=m(i,j);
    }
 }
```

but I am looking for a simpler and faster way if it exist!

Comment: Do not use OpenCV, if at all possible. For example [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) will allow you to [map a rectangular part](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html) of the matrix ([even of the OpenCV matrix](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html)) and will do array bounds checks for you. Sorry, not really an answer to your question but I guess it can save you some pain.

Comment: o=m(cv::Rect(0,0,3,3)) does this work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Matx has a function called get_minor() that does exactly what you want. I don't see it in documentation of OpenCV but it is present inside the implementation. In your case it will be:

```
o = m.get_minor<3,3>(0,0);
```

Template parameters <3,3> is the height and width of small matrix. Value (0,0) is the starting point from which the matrix is cropped.

Comment: Isn't it strange that they have named the method as get_minor ? I was expecting my output matx to not have base_row and base_col like how we have for minors

Answer (score 1):

why not use a simple constructor ?

```
Matx44d m = ...;
Mat33xd o( m(0), m(1), m(2),
           m(4), m(5), m(6),
           m(8), m(9), m(10) );
```

Comment: It is a not a bad idea, but is there any better way to do this?

Comment: I consider it very bad (and dangerous) to hard-code all those indices. An error slips through too easily. That's a lot worse compared to the loop in the question.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
//! creates a matrix header for a part of the bigger matrix
Mat(const Mat& m, const Range& rowRange, const Range& colRange=Range::all());
Mat(const Mat& m, const Rect& roi);
Mat(const Mat& m, const Range* ranges);
```

So you can write:
   Mat part = Mat(A, rect );